# Dell Rack UPS and a single PDU

Tags: ups, rack

Our DELL Rack UPS 1000W has four outlets and we were using one per server. Now the server number is increasing and we are planning to purchase a PDU.

Is it fine to connect the PDU to only one UPS outlet and load the UPS completely unbalanced? Should we purchase two PDUs and try to balance the load?

Thanks.

Comment: have you considered how long your UPS will last with the additional load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the fuses of the different ports, but as the UPS is only 1000W, I would say it is no problem to connect all to a single port (the cables are most likely 10A each, which is around 2300 Watts (EU)), and I guess the ports can atleast handle the maximum of it's cables.